# ROS_canopen correct PDO mapping + EDS modifications?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I have the following setup: Microchip CAN BUS Analyzer + Delta ASDA A2 motor driver + ECMA AC servo motor
Later there will be more motors and drivers, but now the goal is to control a single motor in ROS.
Of course, i both read all the information in wiki.ros and followed all the relevant questions here in the forum, but still my setup is not working, so here i am and would like to ask the parts that are fuzzy.

Quickly i summarize what i've done: (, even though these steps are listed in most of the forum questions and answers, see [jdeleon's question](https://answers.ros.org/question/292882/how-to-control-maxon-mcd-epos-with-ros_canopen-and-ixxat-adapter/) or [Mathias Lüdtke's answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/250174/how-to-control-maxon-motor-by-using-ros_canopen/))

1. I set up the ASDA motor driver to CANopen mode, + Node id to 1, + Baudrate to 500 kBps + Sync (see the link: [CANopen manual](http://www.deltaww.com/filecenter/Products/download/06/060201/Manual/DELTA_IA-ASD_A2-CANopen_UM_EN_20120921.pdf) on page 7)
2. SocketCAN is set up, running
3. URDF is written containing 2 links (base_link, link_1 with visual geometry, collision and inertial tags) + a revolute joint (name:joint_1 with limits, and parent child links) + a transmission(tran1: SimpleTransmission, PositionJointInterface). The URDF was tested in rviz with the joint_state_publisher slider it worked as expected.
4. EDS file: This file was given by the manufacturer ([EDS file](http://www.deltaww.com/Products/PluginWebUserControl/downloadCenterCounter.aspx?DID=4794&DocPath=1&hl=en-US))
5. I configured the [CANopen bus layer](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_chain_node#Configuration), **however i don't know if the heartbeat part is necessary or not (in some forum answers i saw that it was commented out)?** (can.yaml)
6. i configured the [Motor settings](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_motor_node#Configuration) and the [Node layer](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_chain_node#Node_layer) with name:joint_1, id:1 (manipulator1d_motors.yaml) **however i dont't know what should be the default switching state? (is the default 5, i.e., quick stop ok?)**
7. Controller config file containing the joint_state_controller and a joint_1_position_controller (type: position_controllers/JointPositionController, joint: joint_1, required_drive_mode: 1) (manipulator1d_controller.yaml)
8. Launch file containing robot_description urdf, robot_state_publisher node,  joint_state_publisher node, rviz node, + canopen_motor_node with loading the aforementioned can.yaml and manipulator1d_motors.yaml files + load of the controller yaml file, + controller_spawner node with the spawning of the aforementioned controllers
9. rosservice call /driver/init

Of course, in the 9th step the service call crashed, with the messages:

first terminal:

```
[ INFO] [1529055659.976854113]: Using fixed control period: 0.010000000
[ INFO] [1529055664.213323688]: Initializing XXX
[ INFO] [1529055664.213611131]: Current state: 1 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1529055664.213834181]: Current state: 2 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
EMCY: 81#4154201300000000
[ERROR] [1529055667.444154070]: Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >
std::exception::what: boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument
illegal tranistion 0 -> 2
[ INFO] [1529055667.496812113]: Current state: 0 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1529055667.496986914]: Current state: 0 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
```

second terminal:

```
success: False
message: "Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION)\nDynamic exception\
\ type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error>\
\ >\nstd::exception::what: boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid\
\ argument\n; Could not set transition"
```

So at this point i started to read everything and dig into the details. More or less all concerns were focused around the EDS file. On one hand i took into account the answer of Mathias Lüdtke ([here](https://answers.ros.org/question/250969/ros_canopen-dcf_overlay-setting/)):

> Mapping an object to multiple PDOs is not supported

On the other hand i considered the [canopen_402 description](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_402#Overview)

> It recommended to map the control word (object 6040, 0x60400010), the status word (object 6041, 0x60410010) and the operation mode display (object 6061, 0x60610008) to PDOs.

And also:

> The following table lists all supported drive modes and their data objects. The objects used should be mapped to PDOs.

So i changed/updated the original EDS file as follows: (i omitted the objecttype, datatype, limits, accesstype values)

```
[1600sub0]
ParameterName=number of mapped application objects in PDO
DefaultValue=1
PDOMapping=0
ParameterValue=1

[1600sub1]
ParameterName=PDO mapping 1
DefaultValue=0x60400010
PDOMapping=0
ParameterValue=0x60400010

[1601sub0]
ParameterName=number of mapped application objects in PDO
DefaultValue=1
PDOMapping=0
ParameterValue=1

[1601sub1]
ParameterName=PDO mapping 1
DefaultValue=0x60410010
PDOMapping=0

[1602sub0]
ParameterName=number of mapped application objects in PDO
DefaultValue=1
PDOMapping=0
ParameterValue=1

[1602sub1]
ParameterName=PDO mapping 1
DefaultValue=0x60610008
PDOMapping=0

[1603sub0]
ParameterName=number of mapped application objects in PDO
DefaultValue=1
PDOMapping=0
ParameterValue=1

[1603sub1]
ParameterName=PDO mapping 1
DefaultValue=0x607a0020
PDOMapping=0
ParameterValue=0x607a0020
```

**Did i do it correctly? Also it is not written anywhere what should be done with the TPDO mapping?**
(So far i left the TPDO mapping unchanged, as it is in the original EDS file)
**Can someone recommend a working TPDO mapping?**

Next, it is also written [here by Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/question/250174/how-to-control-maxon-motor-by-using-ros_canopen/) that transmission type 1 is required to be used. Therefore i changed the DefaultValue to 1 of the following objects: 1400sub2, 1401sub2, 1402sub2, 1403sub2, 1800sub2, 1801sub2, 1802sub2, 1803sub2

**Again, did i do this right?**

As a result of consecutive fails, i also tried to change the DefaultValue of the object 6060 (Modes of operation) to 1, since i'd like to use Profile position mode.

**Again, no idea if this was a right step?!**

After these modifications, i have different crash messages:
first terminal:

```
[ INFO] [1529064851.906620887]: Using fixed control period: 0.010000000
[ INFO] [1529064854.740534586]: Initializing XXX
[ INFO] [1529064854.740841900]: Current state: 1 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1529064854.741085497]: Current state: 2 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
EMCY: 81#4154201300000000
EMCY: 81#0000000000000000
EMCY: 81#4154201300000000
[ WARN] [1529064856.861450863]: RPDO timeout
[ INFO] [1529064866.811915681]: Current state: 2 device error: system:125 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1529064866.812005487]: Current state: 0 device error: system:125 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1529064866.812045836]: Current state: 0 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1529064866.812114294]: Current state: 0 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
```

second terminal:

```
success: False
message: "Transition timeout; Could not enable motor; Transition timeout"
```

Here i am stuck, and don't really know what to do.
Can someone help me? What to do, what to try? What is wrong with my setup?

I can extend this post, even i can upload the content of the files (yaml, launch, etc.) if its necessary.

Thank you in advance.
Best regards,
Akos

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294210/ros_canopen-correct-pdo-mapping-+-eds-modifications?/) by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-06-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Did i do it correctly? Also it is not written anywhere what should be done with the TPDO mapping?

No. The PDO settings should go into the `ParameterValue` entries. `DefaulValue` should contain the values after boot-up of the devices.
Statuses are TPDOs (sent by the device), commands are RPDOs (received by the device).

> Can someone recommend a working TPDO mapping?

The Care-O-bot mapping can be found in [canopen_test_utils](https://github.com/ipa320/canopen_test_utils/blob/indigo-devel/scripts/). These scripts can even be called to patch an EDS to form a DCF.
As an alternative, you can use CANeds to set-up the PDO mapping.

> As a result of consecutive fails, i also tried to change the DefaultValue

Don't change `DefaultValue`. `ros_canopen`  compares `DefaultValue`  and `ParameterValue`  and will only send out the SDO if somethings needs to be changed.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2018-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2018-06-20**:
Hello Mathias! Thank you for the help.
I also posted a new question related to the canopen_test_utils package: [#q294570](https://answers.ros.org/question/294570/canopen-test-based-on-the-canopen_test_utils-package/)
Can you give a hint what causes the 'hardware_interface:' ERROR? Thanks in advance

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2018-06-20**:
I am going to redo the modification of the original EDS file where i will add the ParameterValue as it is given in the Care-O-bot dfc, and i wil not change the DefaultValue. Thanks again!

**Comment by [martinlucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/74707/martinlucan/) on 2021-12-06**:
Hi @akosodry, did you find out what is the correct `switching_state` value? I could not find any documentation regarding this parameter.